# Probability and Roots of Equations

Tags: probability, roots, expected-value

I have the following question:

> Suppose that $P(X=0) = 1 - P(X=1)$. If $E[X] = 3Var[X]$, find $P(X=0)$

From the definition of expected value, we know $E[X] = P(X=1)$. So there are two ways I solved this:

(1) Abbreviate $P(X=1)$ as $p$. Then $p = 3p(1-p)$ and so $p=2/3$ and $P(X=0) = 1/3$

(2) Note that $P(X=1) = 1 - P(X=0)$. Letting $P(X=0)$ be abbreviated as $q$, we then have $(1-q)=3(1-q)(1-(1-q))$. This simplifies to $3q^2 - 4q + 1 =0$ which has roots $q = \{2/3, 1\}$, implying that $P(X=0)$ can be either $1/3$ or $0$.

It seems to me that $P(X=0) = 0$ shouldn't be a solution, but if we were to only follow method (2), I'm not entirely sure how to see that $P(X=0) = 0$ is not a valid solution.

Comment: In my opinion $p=0$ is a valid solution, since $p\in [0,1]$ if $X$ is Bernoulli distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a flaw in your method (1). In that case, $P(X=1)=p=0$ is possible. Then $X\equiv 0$ with $E(X)=\operatorname{Var}(X)=0$.

In your second method, you were actually letting $q:=P(X=0)$ and more importantly, $$0=3q^2-4q+1=(3q-1)(q-1),$$ whose roots are $1/3$ and $1$. In other words, $P(X=1)$ takes value from $\{2/3,0\}$, the same as (1). Thus it is merely a calculation mistake.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the error; I flipped the q and P(X=0) in my mind when I was writing it down. This question comes from Ross' Introduction to Probability, and he only mentions that the solution is P(X=0) = 1/3, so I suppose he must be implying that this is the only non-trivial solution.

Comment: I think so, as in most cases we would like $p\in(0,1)$.